# When use Pants to build Django it raise "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named"

Tags: python, django, pants, starlark

I configured Pantsbuild for our Django project, and everything worked neatly. Here is my `BUILD` file:

```
python_requirement(
    name="django",
    requirements=["django==4.1.1"],
)


python_sources(
    name="lib",
    dependencies=[
        ":django",
        "//src/jango/jango",
    ],
)

pex_binary(
    name="manage",
    entry_point="manage.py",
    restartable=True,
)
```

but when I added `django-filter`, and run the code with the following command:

```bash
./pants run src/jango:manage -- runserver
```

I faced an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/home/xurvan/monorepo/src/jango/manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    import django_filters
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_filters'
```

I also installed Django Rest Framework, and it works fine. But I have the same problem with `django-cors-headers`. I don't understand the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not understand the reason behind strange behavior, but all we need to do is to disable Django autoreloader. As official Pantsbuild group wrote in their [Github](https://github.com/pantsbuild/example-django):

> with `runserver` we turn off Django's autoreloader, since we rely on Pants's own file-watching instead, by setting `restartable=True` on the `pex_binary` targets for `manage.py`

So running code with the following command solved my problem:

```
./pants run src/jango:manage -- runserver --noreload
```