# Django manage.py ModuleNotFoundError with Pants

Tags: django, django-manage.py, pants

First time poster, so let me know if I need to provide more info!
I have a Django project of the following structure:

```
a/b/c/d/
├── e
│   ├── BUILD.pants
│   ├── myapp
│   │   ├── BUILD.pants
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── ...
│   │   └── tests
│   ├── BUILD.pants
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── ...
│   └── wsgi.py
├── BUILD.pants
├── ...
└── manage.py
```

The Django app can be run using `manage.py runserver` perfectly fine, but it uses relative and app-level imports which causes Pants and Pyright issues within my repo. I want to set it up on Pants anyways, so I have switched all my relative imports to absolute imports (which breaks it running via Django directly).

This is my BUILD.pants at a/b/c/d:

```
python_sources()

pex_binary(
    name="manage",
    entry_point="manage.py",
    dependencies=["a/b/c/d/e"],
    restartable=True,
)
```

Running manage.py through Pants, instead of starting the app, produces the following:

```
./pants run a/b/c/d:manage -- runserver --noreload
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/artificialask/.pex/unzipped_pexes/900cb0387e270fc2eadde5a3883453a34b9a796e/__main__.py", line 103, in <module>
    bootstrap_pex(__entry_point__, execute=__execute__, venv_dir=__venv_dir__)
  File "/home/artificialask/.pex/unzipped_pexes/900cb0387e270fc2eadde5a3883453a34b9a796e/.bootstrap/pex/pex_bootstrapper.py", line 599, in bootstrap_pex
    pex.PEX(entry_point).execute()
  File "/home/artificialask/.pex/unzipped_pexes/900cb0387e270fc2eadde5a3883453a34b9a796e/.bootstrap/pex/pex.py", line 551, in execute
    sys.exit(self._wrap_coverage(self._wrap_profiling, self._execute))
  File "/home/artificialask/.pex/unzipped_pexes/900cb0387e270fc2eadde5a3883453a34b9a796e/.bootstrap/pex/pex.py", line 458, in _wrap_coverage
    return runner(*args)
  File "/home/artificialask/.pex/unzipped_pexes/900cb0387e270fc2eadde5a3883453a34b9a796e/.bootstrap/pex/pex.py", line 489, in _wrap_profiling
    return runner(*args)
  File "/home/artificialask/.pex/unzipped_pexes/900cb0387e270fc2eadde5a3883453a34b9a796e/.bootstrap/pex/pex.py", line 594, in _execute
    return self.execute_entry(
  File "/home/artificialask/.pex/unzipped_pexes/900cb0387e270fc2eadde5a3883453a34b9a796e/.bootstrap/pex/pex.py", line 775, in execute_entry
    return self.execute_module(entry_point.module)
  File "/home/artificialask/.pex/unzipped_pexes/900cb0387e270fc2eadde5a3883453a34b9a796e/.bootstrap/pex/pex.py", line 783, in execute_module
    runpy.run_module(module_name, run_name="__main__", alter_sys=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 207, in run_module
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/artificialask/.pex/unzipped_pexes/900cb0387e270fc2eadde5a3883453a34b9a796e/a/b/c/d/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/artificialask/.pex/unzipped_pexes/900cb0387e270fc2eadde5a3883453a34b9a796e/a/b/c/d/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/artificialask/.pex/installed_wheels/ba7b3b60845048a44d2e41a4e4a52139aed31176b2358657f84b4e506efcde25/Django-4.1.7-py3-none-any.whl/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/artificialask/.pex/installed_wheels/ba7b3b60845048a44d2e41a4e4a52139aed31176b2358657f84b4e506efcde25/Django-4.1.7-py3-none-any.whl/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 420, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/artificialask/.pex/installed_wheels/ba7b3b60845048a44d2e41a4e4a52139aed31176b2358657f84b4e506efcde25/Django-4.1.7-py3-none-any.whl/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/artificialask/.pex/installed_wheels/ba7b3b60845048a44d2e41a4e4a52139aed31176b2358657f84b4e506efcde25/Django-4.1.7-py3-none-any.whl/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/artificialask/.pex/installed_wheels/ba7b3b60845048a44d2e41a4e4a52139aed31176b2358657f84b4e506efcde25/Django-4.1.7-py3-none-any.whl/django/apps/config.py", line 193, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'd'
```

In `manage.py main()` it looks like the offending line is:

`os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'b.c.d.e.settings')`.
(In my repo all absolute imports are relative to `b`, even though the file is located in directory `a/b`). Trying to change this line to some other import path will unsurprisingly give the same error, just with a different module not being found.

I've tried:
[This example repo](https://github.com/pantsbuild/example-django) structure is a bit different because it uses a service architecture, but I tried to mimic the patterns I could pick out. `--noreload` also doesn't do anything for me.
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73685724/when-use-pants-to-build-django-it-raise-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named) I've used to try and structure my build files, but I don't think this is the same core issue, since running `./pants dependencies` shows the correct dependencies for my directories.

I think the issue is something silly, where I'm not using the correct directory structure/import structure in one of the build/settings files, but I've tried all the combinations I can think of and nothing seems to work. I'm a total noob with Pants so I'm not sure how to setup the pex_binary() and python_sources() in the BUILD.pants files.

Comment: Can you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

For Django in particular, it's often easier to get it to work by running `manage.py` from within the repo sources rather than hermetically in a pants sandbox.

Try this:

```py
python_sources(
  overrides={
    "manage.py": dict(
      run_goal_use_sandbox=False,
    )
  }
)
```

Then:

```bash
pants run a/b/c/d/manage.py ...
```

https://www.pantsbuild.org/docs/reference-python_source#coderun_goal_use_sandboxcode